Calculating radius of curvature of a boundary represented by data points
I have a set of data points that look something like this.
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6 ..., n] (essentially the index)
y = [2,4,3,5,1,9,..., mn] (some random values for each index)
Parametric radius of curvature information is given as:
\begin{equation}
R = \frac{\left( x'^2 + y'^2 \right)^{3/2}}{\left| x' y'' - y' x'' \right|}
\end{equation}
Now,I would like to define some sort of measure that calculates the curvature of this function. Essentially it would give a high measure for a sharp data set (of y values) and a low one for smooth data set.
How should I do this in python? Should I do some sort of circle fitting between 3 points and using Heron's formula?

Perhaps this helps: Jupyter Notebook

Hey! I didnt see this earlier. Excellent solution! Thank you so much!
